# Sorted list and print results

Tags: python

I have following program. I wanted to sort list a and list b and store the results in m and n.

```
a = ['c','a','t']
b = ['t','a','c']
m = a.sort()
n = b.sort()
print(m,n)
```

**Actual output:**

```
(None, None)
```

**Expected:**

```
(['a','c','t'], ['a','c','t'])
```

Comment: `print(a,b)` because `.sort()` is inplace

Comment: a.sort() will change a itself, and return None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.sort()` returns `None` as it sorts the list in place and doesn't return the list back. But wheras sorted will.

```
a = ['c','a','t']
b = ['t','a','c']
m = sorted(a)
n = sorted(b)
print(m,n)
```

Comment: Oh yes. `None`. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `sort()` method changes `a, b` themselves, and doesn't return anything. If you want to create sorted copies, do instead

```
m = sorted(a)
n = sorted(b)
```

Comment: @jpp: correct, I somehow remembered that it returned a generator expression

Comment: Doesn't return anything isn't technically correct. `list.sort` returns `None`.

Comment: @jpp: everything that has no `return` returns `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`sort()` sorts the list inplace without creating new lists

you can either print a and b after `sort()`

or use `sorted(a)` and `sorted(b)` which will create new lists keeping original lists as it is

Answer (score 0):

From the docs: The method `sort()` does not return any value but it changes from the original list. You therefore either use

```
a = ['c','a','t']
b = ['t','a','c']
a.sort()
b.sort()
print(a, b)
```

or use `sorted()`, which returns a sorted list from the given iterable.

```
a = ['c','a','t']
b = ['t','a','c']
m = sorted(a)
n = sorted(b)
print(m, n)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted).

```
>>> a = ['c','a','t']
>>> b = ['t','a','c']
>>> m = sorted(a)
>>> n = sorted(b)
>>> m
['a', 'c', 't']
>>> n
['a', 'c', 't']
```

---

a.sort() changes ***a*** itself, and return None.

```
>>> a = ['c','a','t']
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
['a', 'c', 't']
```

Comment: a.sort() will change a itself, and return None

Answer (score -1):

.`sort()` method do the sorting `inplace` and sort itself is a void function without any output as you can see ,so your original array is sorted now

Answer (score -2):

It's because sort, modifies the list inplace and returns nothing, your code fixed:

```
a = ['c','a','t']
b = ['t','a','c']
a.sort()
b.sort()
print(a,b)
```

Comment: Well, it does return an object. That object is `None`.

Comment: @jpp edited it, thanks!

Comment: Nope still wrong, it does return something. That something is `None`.

Comment: Nope it does returns nothing, if you try to name what it returns it is none object because it is filled with nothing

Comment: Try `print(a.sort())`. What do you see? `None` object isn't "filled with nothing".

Comment: You implicitly create an object when using print, but  if you keep the line `a.sort()` no object is being created not even a none object. If you don't try to name or somewhat use the result of `sort()` no object is created.